# postgres sequence not incrementing

Tags: java, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I created a PostgreSQL sequence on a PostgreSQL 10.7 dB  called `markush_seq`
I read from the seq

```
select nextval('markush_seq’)` )
```

using a java web service:
When I run the web service on eclipse (using java 1.8.161) or call the sequence direct from SQL developer, it works fine and the sequence increments by 1 each time eg:

```
http://localhost:8086/wipdbws/read-markush-seq
```

> 21767823690
>
> 21767823691
>
> 21767823692

However when I run the webservice on AWS (which uses java 1.8.252)  and read from the seq using:

```
https://aws-location/wipdbws/read-markush-seq
```

I get the sequence number returned as eg:

> 21767823692
>
> 21767823702
>
> 21767823693
>
> 21767823703
>
> 21767823694
>
> 21767823704

The sequence in AWS appears to be a combination of 2 incrementing sequences, 10 apart.
It’s the same java code, the only thing that has changed is:

1. The location of the webservice

   a. AWS – USWEST

   b. Eclipse - London
2. The java version:

   a. 1.8.161 in London

   b. 1.8.252 in US WEST

The seq details are:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.sequences
where sequence_name='markush_seq';
```

[image: seq details]

```
select * from pg_sequences where sequencename='markush_seq';
```

[image: sql output]

Any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: Just for clarity, you meant you have two different PostgreSQL DBs, right? one locally and another in AWS.

Comment: Please post output of `select * from pg_sequences where sequencename='markush_seq';` for each database.

Comment: Nope, I have 1 database and 1 sequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely due to  multiple sessions accessing the sequence and sequence cache settings.

[Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-createsequence.html) says:

> although multiple sessions are guaranteed to allocate distinct
>   sequence values, the values might be generated out of sequence when
>   all the sessions are considered. For example, with a cache setting of
>   10, session A might reserve values 1..10 and return nextval=1, then
>   session B might reserve values 11..20 and return nextval=11 before
>   session A has generated nextval=2. Thus, with a cache setting of one
>   it is safe to assume that nextval values are generated sequentially;
>   with a cache setting greater than one you should only assume that the
>   nextval values are all distinct, not that they are generated purely
>   sequentially. Also, last_value will reflect the latest value reserved
>   by any session, whether or not it has yet been returned by nextval.

Comment: I don't think so, it's in development , just me accessing it

Comment: Please post requested output in text mode because INFORMATION_SCHEMA has less information than PG system catalog.

Comment: Sequence has`cache_size=10`. Are your sure that your web service does not have several database connections ?

Comment: I'm not actually sure how many connetion I have. I'm using spring boot, there's nothing in application.properties so I presume it's the default connection pool size? But it's only me accessing the webService

Comment: That chache size of 10  looks like the culprit. I'll change it to 1 and report back

Comment: Once I changed the cache size to 1 the problem dissapeared, thanks for the help.